# Cosmos DB - Graph API - Export graphSON and try to import it with Migration tool

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases

I inserted a few Vertices and Edges in a new graph.
I've saved the resulting grapSON in a json file.
Then I tried to import that json file into a new graph with the Migration tool.
It only partially worked. I had a new graph with my Vertices but they had no properties or Edges like that:

```
{
"id": "c39f435b-350e-4d08-a7b6-dfcadbe4e9c5",
"label": "user",
"type": "vertex",
"_isFixedPosition": true,
"_isRoot": true
```

}

Does anyone knows how to "trick" the migration tool to create new graphs?
I'm trying to migrate an existing SQL DB to a graph so I could generate the graphSON programatically.

Comment: The migration tools you used specifically for SQL API and don't support the Graph schema, and the bulk import tools for Graph API are currently in private preview. If you contact askcosmosdbgraphapi@microsoft.com the team can provide access to the preview tools.

Comment: Tks. I actually had a chat with the MS team and they explained me how to use the migration tool as it is right now to achieve what I want. They also said they would answer the question here and that's why I haven't done it myself yet.

Comment: @François What was the process? I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2):

A way I just worked out is to use the Data Migration Tool to export the current graph database (connect as a Documents DB) as a JSON file. Then on the portal import the exported JSON.

Added the graph with vertices and edges in tact.